# Get file information to download files generates HttpError 404 googleapis

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-app-engine

With this code **I can** download a file from Google Drive, it downloads me into a file without extension and with a random name in a temporary folder. The file size is correct and the same as the original file.

```
@app.route('/download_from_drive', methods=['POST'])
def download_from_drive():
    data = flask_request.get_json()
    url = data.get('url')

    print(url)

    # Extract the file ID from the Google Drive URL
    file_id = url.split('id=')[-1]

    # Create a temporary file for download
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_file:
        print("File downloaded to:", temp_file.name)
        # Get the contents of the file
        request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
        fh = io.FileIO(temp_file.name, 'wb')
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
        done = False
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))

    return jsonify({'message': 'Download completed successfully!'})
```

But when I try to download the file with its original name I get a **404** error. This is unexpected behavior since I am the owner of the file and I use credentials.json and token.json (taken from my google cloud project) which allow me to find my files

The code that gives me problems is this:

```
def extract_drive_file_id(file_url):
    try:
        # Extract the file ID from the Google Drive link
        file_id = file_url.split('/')[-1]
        return file_id
    except IndexError:
        return None

@app.route('/download_from_drive', methods=['POST'])
def download_from_drive():
    data = flask_request.get_json()
    url = data.get('url')

    # Extract the file ID from the Google Drive URL
    file_id = url.split('id=')[-1]

    # Get file information
    file_info = drive_service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()
    file_name = file_info['name']

    # Create a file with the original file name for download
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as file:
        print("File downloaded to:", file_name)
        # Get the contents of the file
        request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
        fh = io.FileIO(file_name, 'wb')
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
        done = False
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))

    return jsonify({'message': 'Download completed successfully!'})
```

Errors from Console/Dev

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HAaaT298cUncQ**************  
loadMore.js:20 
        
        
       POST http://localhost:5004/download_from_drive 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
uploadToTelegram @ loadMore.js:20
(anonymous) @ loadMore.js:15
VM1322:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
Promise.then (async)
uploadToTelegram @ loadMore.js:28
(anonymous) @ loadMore.js:15

    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 938, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1HAaaT298cUncQ**************?alt=json returned "File not found: 1HAaaT298cUncQ**************.". Details: "[{'message': 'File not found: 1HAaaT298cUncQ**************.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'location': 'fileId', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]">
```

I read [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v2/files/get?hl=it) to understand better

Comment: About `But when I try to download the file with its original name I get a 404 error. `, where does your error occur in your showing script? By the way, can I ask you about the details of the relationship between your question and Google Apps Script?

Comment: the error occurs at this point ```file_info = drive_service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()```  i.e. when I try to get the information about the file I want to download (the filename) so that it doesn't have a random name and no extension and at that moment it tells me that it can't find the file, even though the extracted ID is actually correct - The paradox is that by downloading the ID as a temporary file and not as a file with its original name, the file is downloaded (but with a random name and without an extension)